# Android code to uploading image audio video to server

Tags: android, json, xml

I have small problem when I am uploading data to server when I debug I am getting an error. When I debug it exit and return 0.

```
if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + filepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" + filepath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        }
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20150719_203955.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear 'PERMISSION DENIED' are you sure you've put the right permissions in the manifest?

Comment: @bojjabenarjee: *please it urgend* -  Despite the spelling error this is very rude to force us to help you in a urgend way. Please see the [help] and read how to behave here.

Comment: You have to learn `Testing` strategy, It will helps you in future.